# Getting run-time 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed when using cells

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()
      Dim sht As Worksheet
      Dim LastRow As Long
      Dim LastColumn As Long
      Dim StartCell As Range
      Dim objTable As ListObject

      Dim WS_Count As Integer
      Dim I As Integer

      WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


       For I = 1 To WS_Count
            Set sht = Worksheets(I)
            Set StartCell = Range("A2")

            LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            ' error on next line
            sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Select

            Set objTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Selection, , xlYes)

            MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

            Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean this? `Set StartCell = sht.Range("A2")` ?

Comment: You can't select the range unless you are on that sheet

Comment: Do you really need `startcell.row`? it's just 2

Comment: Nice of you to come back and check for replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, modified version of your code:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim rngStart As Range
    Dim rngTolist As Range
    Dim objTable As ListObject

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Set rngStart = sht.Range("A2")

        LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, rngStart.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = sht.Cells(rngStart.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set rngTolist = sht.Range(rngStart, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
        Set objTable = sht.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rngTolist, , xlYes)

        MsgBox sht.Name & ", " & objTable.Name

    Next

End Sub
```